# Getting coefficients of Curve25519

Tags: elliptic-curves

I want to extract coefficient $A$ and $B$ from Curve25519 represented in Montgomery form as $B v^2 = u^3 + A u^2 + u$.

What are the $A$ and $B$ coefficients of Curve25519 in Montgomery form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation for a [Montgomery curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve) is:

$B y^2 = x^3 +A x^2 + x$

The [Curve25519 paper](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf) states the Curve25519 equation on page 2:

$y^2 = x^3 + 486662x^2 + x \pmod {2^{255}-19}$

Thus

$A=486662$ and $B = 1$.